# Bootstrap Footer sticky bottom - scrollbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sticky-footer

am wandering what I did wrong over here. Am trying to get rid of the scrollbar (vertical). I have tried removing the paddings and even adjusting the height. Can't figure out what I may have missed out. Help much appreciated

http://jsfiddle.net/jSB53/embedded/result/

```
/* Sticky footer styles
      -------------------------------------------------- */

html, body {
    height: 100%;/* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
}
/* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
#wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    /* Negative indent footer by it's height */
    margin: 0 auto -70px;
     /* Pad bottom by footer height */
  padding: 0 0 60px;
}

#footer {
    background-color: #ee3124;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 20px 0 0;
}

.navbar-default {
    border-bottom: 5px #ee3124 solid;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 33px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 4px -2px #C7C7C7;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 4px -2px #C7C7C7;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 4px -2px #C7C7C7;

}

/* Lastly, apply responsive CSS fixes as necessary */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
#footer {
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the horizontal or vertical or both?

Comment: the scrollbar only occurs vertically =)))

Comment: There is a hori scrollbar on the bottom because if the negative margin in your media query.

Comment: Figured out myself. It was a mistake on my side. Added margin to a div that caused the scrolling bar to appear. my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've set the height of the footer to 70px, you need to adjust the #wrap bottom padding too..

```
/* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
#wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  /* Negative indent footer by its height */
  margin: 0 auto -70px;
  /* Pad bottom by footer height */
  padding: 0 0 70px;
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/rl77rU0NgR